# Automating Google

Tags: web, automation

Hello StackOverFlow members, this is a general knowledge based question regarding Google.

My goal : To automate a web page such as Google. 
The over-all objective is to create a web browser that automates a Google search with button click event. 
 1. Navigate to Google.com
 2. Click search bar 
 3. Enter text ("Define Hello" for example)
 4. Click search

I have seen add-ons such as selenium for Firefox, this is a primary example of what I wish to achieve, however I want my application to be stand-alone meaning fully source/not using a separate internet browser like Firefox, but rather using my internet browser project that I have built.

So my question is, what do I need to look at for achieving this?

I have background in C# and the web browser is built, but when using google for searches like "Web browser automation" I do not find what I am looking for, there's no relevant source for this to my knowledge.

Any kind of guidance would be greatly appreciated, is this an application that would be built using Java, would I need a server?

Thanks for any help you experienced programmers can give, if you have any relevant questions I'll be sure to update this op with the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: "but rather using my internet browser project that I have built" we have no idea what this is / how it works / how to interact with it. You are the only one who can answer this question. Even if it was a "normal" known user agent this question would still be too broad to answer.

Comment: I meant it only as a mention of my browser, the browser is simple, URL bar & Go button.. I want this go button to navigate me to a google search of "Hello" automatically, I do not know how to do that without the use of applications such as Selenium. I do not want to use other DLL imports, I want a stand-alone google automation application

Answer (score 0):

You can try with AutoIT -  https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Its an opensource and very easy to use. If you have knowledge of any programming language then this is very easy to understand and implement.